# Can I make this macro faster?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I improve the speed of  this macro?

My macro is:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "RemplazoString"
Sub MACRO()
    bAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Cells.Replace What:="T:\", Replacement:="T:\Gestion\", LookAt:=xlPart
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bAlerts
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here for additional macro speed improvements:

- http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/
- http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

In particular for your code you can change:

1. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
2. `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`
3. `Application.EnableEvents = False` (This is optional but I usually put it in my code in case I have events in my code)

Also I would be careful with those above an put a en error handler if you don't want to freeze your Excel window if an error happens inside your Sub.

So your code would look like follows:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "RemplazoString"
Sub MACRO()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    'Speed Up block
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    '---
    bAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Cells.Replace What:="T:\", Replacement:="T:\Gestion\", LookAt:=xlPart
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bAlerts

    'Leave speed up settings as default
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    '---
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'Leave speed up settings as default
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 would also recommend a 'for each' as superior to 'for i ' approach.